# numpy csv import problem

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am having some difficulty with importing data from a `.csv` file. I am simply trying to import the data and print the max value. Here is my code:

```
>>> x, y = numpy.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(4,5), unpack=True)
>>> print 'max =', max(x)
```

When I enter the above code, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I tried to change the data type using the `dtype=int` argument, but it threw the same error. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *Which* line gives the error?

Comment: If your file only contains a single line, `loadtxt()` unfortunately returns a scalar for `x` and `y` instead of an array with a single entry.  Is there only one line in your file?

Comment: The `data.csv` file contains one row of data with numerous columns. Is the solution to add more rows to the 'data.csv` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `loadtxt()` is unfortunately a bit inconistent:  If there is only one line in your file, `x` and `y` will be scalars, but for more than one line, they will be arrays.  The Python built-in `max()` only works for iterables, so it only works in the latter case.

Using the Python built-in `max()` function instead of `numpy.max()` is inefficient for NumPy arrays anyway.  So a solution is to use

```
print x.max()
```

or

```
print numpy.max(x)
```

in the second line.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I appreciate you taking the time to explain things so clearly.